# WPF TextBox Scrollbars actually visible or not?

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I have a TextBox in a WPF Project whose verticalscrollbar visibility is set to Auto. When I set a text in it at Runtime the vertical scroll bar becomes visible when text is more and vertical scroll bar hides when text is less.

What i want is if when i assign a large text to it (and verticalscrollbar becomes visible) then i will run a recursive loop which will reduce font size to a level till the scroll bar become hidden. I want to get the actual visibility value of verticalscrollbar.

In code behind the verticalscrollbarvisibility property always gives auto. (i think boz its set to auto in XAML).

// If my approach is wrong for this problem please let me know that also.

Comment: Sorry about the banal question, I may understand wrong what you need... but setting a textbox maxlength is not enough?

Comment: I found it. I passed my textbox in a function (public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject) to gets its child scrollviewer. (In Google FindVisualChild function to get that function)

It returns me ScrollViewer whose visibility property is what i wanted.

Comment: Would it not be better just to re-template the `TextBox` so that it uses a `ViewBox` rather than a `ScrollViewer`? Then it will automatically scale the content to the available size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. I passed my textbox in the function

```
ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(mytextbox);
if (sv != null)
{
    // do something with ScrollViewer
}

public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }

            T childItem = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childItem != null) return childItem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It returns me ScrollViewer whose visibility property is what i wanted.